# I could not see compsiting,scene in blender

Tags: edit-mode, scene, compositing-nodes

[image]
In the upper part as you can see there is no scene,default it has gone to 3

Answer (score 2):

The top header I can see in your screenshot belongs to a second 3D view window. Turn it to an Info window ("i" icon) and you will find what you're looking for.

[image]